# Automatic alert for Privacy Settings in iOS 10 doesn't show up

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, info-plist

I've assumed that putting `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` into info.plist will automatically trigger the alert view (at appropriate time)  which will among the other things, show the (localized) error defined in InfoPlist.strings(current language). I assumed something like that, because of this statement from the docs:

> NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription (String - iOS) This key lets
>   you describe the reason your app uses Bluetooth. When the system
>   prompts the user to allow usage, the value that you provide for this
>   key is displayed as part of the alert.

Take a look at into this part:

> **When the system prompts** the user to allow usage ...

IMO, this means that alert will be popped out automatically, rather than manually in the code by me.

I am using :

`CoreBluetooth` framework and many of its classes like:

`CBPeripheral`, `CBCharacteristic`, `CBCentralManager` etc. so I guess this alert should pop out. Of course, I can pop out the alert view by myself on the first use of Bluetooth, but I thought that point of these info.plist keys is, actually to warn the user automatically...

Comment: I don't believe that iOS currently prompts the user in regard to BLE use in the background, but you must specify the key anyway.  There is no requirement for you to notify the user either

Comment: @Paulw11 This seems to be a correct answer, at least it is what I am seeing currently. System obviously doesn't prompt about permissions automatically, like in the case of say, recording of audio...

Answer (score 0):

Not quite...

I would *hate* to have iOS automatically pop up every permission request dialog when the app first runs. Much better to allow me to show "Can I use the camera?" the first time the user gets to the section of my app where the camera is used, and "Can I use Bluetooth" when that section is used.

So, the strings are required so the users are not presented with generic "App wants to use Bluetooth" requests. Instead, you have to provide a suitably *informative* string (subject to the reviewer's opinion, of course).

But it won't be presented to the user until **you** want it to be shown.

Comment: Then I misunderstood the part *When the system prompts the user* I guess... But do you have any proof (ideally from the docs) that system won't show this alert automatically?

Comment: Yeah... the language can be confusing. There is no way for us to "ask for permission" - we can only initiate an action that *requires* permission, at which point *"the system prompts the user..."*. That's how I read it, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already answered the system popup and have an entry in the iOS settings? In this case iOS will not ask anymore.

Comment: Well, it doesn't show up even if I uninstall the app and re-install it again... So I guess that what you are saying was not a thing...